# Is there a characterisation of additive subgroups of the cartesian product of the real line by itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is well known that any  non trivial additive subgroup $(G ,+)$
of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is either  a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or
has the form  $a\mathbb{Z}, $ for some $a>0$. Now, my question is:
Can we describe/characterize non trivial additive subgroups of
$(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}, +)?$  Thanks.  I appreciate feedbacks I got before submitting this question
again.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is classify _closed_ subgroups.  Note that the classification you refer to in the case of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is quite coarse: the class of dense subgroups is huge and includes a huge variety of different subgroups.  The only sense in which they are the same is that they have the same _closure_.

Comment: I reformulated the question. I am looking just for the additive aspect of the subgroups. Thanks for the feedback.